# jquery validate Max method. How can I compare the values of two fields in the same form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I got a form with two number fields (Number1  Number2).
'Number2' can't be greater than 'Number1.

I try this:

```
Number2: {
   required: true,
   digits: true,
   max: $('#Number1').val()
},
```

But doesn't work...
Any idea, please!!!

Comment: Please provide a more complete demo and clarify exactly what you mean by "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return it from within a function so that it's re-evaluated every time the value of `Number2` is changed...

```
Number2: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    max: function() {
        return parseInt($('#Number1').val());
    }
}
```

Proof-of-concept demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/zzzarym2/

Comment: I'm not sure i understand question as it but for sure OP didn't have posted enough context to make his question clear enough. ***EDIT*** seeing your jsFiddle makes question more clear, thx!

Comment: @A.Wolff, agreed the question is written poorly.  I'm pretty experienced with this plugin, however, I'm still not sure that's what he meant... anything else could be wrong with it too.

Comment: Great! Sorry about the poor context... The code in the jsFiddle works fine! Thanks!!!